# How do I merge dictionaries together, using weights?

Tags: python, dictionary, computer-science

```
d1 = {'weight':1, 'data': { 'apples': 8, 'oranges': 7 } }
d2 = {'weight':3, 'data': { 'apples': 4, 'bananas': 3 } }
all_dictionaries = [d1, d2, ... ]

def mergeDictionariesWithWeight(all_dictionaries)
```

How do I merge these dictionaries together (if overlap, multiple value with the weight)

The function would return:

```
{ 'apples': 4, 'oranges': 7, 'bananas': 3 }
```

Apples is `4` because `8 * .25 + 4 * .75`

Edit: I just wrote one that takes the average, something like this. But of course it's really different from what I want to do, because I stick everything in a list and just divide by the length.

```
result = {}
keymap = {}
for the_dict in dlist:
    for (k, v) in the_dict.items():
        if not keymap.has_key(k):
            keymap[k] = []
        keymap[k].append(v)
for (k, v) in keymap.items():
    average = sum(int(x) for x in keymap[k]) / float(len(keymap[k]))
    result[k] = float(average)
return result
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d=defaultdict(lambda:(0,0))
>>> for D in all_dictionaries:
...   weight = D['weight']
...   for k,v in D['data'].items():
...     d[k]=d[k][0]+weight*v,d[k][1]+weight
... 
>>> dict((k,v[0]/v[1]) for k,v in d.items())
{'apples': 5, 'oranges': 7, 'bananas': 3}
```

If you need floating point result

```
>>> dict((k,1.*v[0]/v[1]) for k,v in d.items())
{'apples': 5.0, 'oranges': 7.0, 'bananas': 3.0}
```

Notes about **[defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)**

Often you see `defaultdict(int)` or `defaultdict(list)` maybe even `defaultdict(set)`.  The argument to defaultdict must be callable with no parameters. The result of calling this parameter is used whenever a key is found to be missing. ie - calling this returns the *default value* for the dictionary

for example

```
>>> d=defaultdict(int)
>>> d[1]
0
>>> d['foo']
0
```

This is often used for counting things up because `int()` returns 0. If you want the default value to be 1 instead of 0, it's more tricky because you can't pass a parameter to int, but all you need is a callable that returns 1. This can be accomplished without too much fuss by using a **[lambda](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-forms)** function.

```
>>> d=defaultdict(lambda:1)
>>> d[1]
1
>>> d['foo']
1
```

In this answer, I want to keep track of the weighted total, and the total of the weights. I can do this by using a 2-tuple as the default value.

```
>>> d=defaultdict(lambda:(0,0))
>>> d[1]
(0, 0)
>>> d['foo']
(0, 0)
```

Comment: +1 I'd hoist `D['weight']` outside of the loop, but otherwise perfect.

Comment: @hughdbrown, there I did it just for you.

Comment: Wow this is amazingly pythonic. Can you explain what the lambda does? Thx!

Comment: @TIMEX, I added some explanation

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that first uses gathers the items into a list using a temporary dict, and then computes the final weighted dict. It can probably be done without a temporary, but this is easy to understand.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def mergeDictionariesWithWeight(dlist):
    tmp = defaultdict(list)
    for d in dlist:
        weight = d['weight']
        for k, v in d['data'].items():
            tmp[k].append((weight, v))
    r = {}
    for k, v in tmp.items():
        # If there's just one item, ignore the weight
        if len(v) == 1:
            r[k] = v[0][1]
        else:
            total_weight = sum((x[0] for x in v), 0.0)
            r[k] = sum(x[1] * x[0]/total_weight for x in v)
    return r
```

Returns: {'apples': 5.0, 'oranges': 7, 'bananas': 3} (because 8 * .25 + 4 * .75 = 5.0)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```py
def mergeDictionariesWithWeight(all_dictionaries):
    weightSum = 0
    weightDictionary ={}    

    for dictionary in all_dictionaries: 

        weight = dictionary['weight']
        data = dictionary['data']

        #find the total weight of the elements in data
        for (k,v) in data.items(): 
            if k in weightDictionary:
                weightDictionary[k] += weight*v
        weightSum += weight 
        #normalize the results by deviding by the weight sum
        for (key, value) in weightDictionary:
            weightDictionary[key] = value / float(weightSum)
    return weightDictionary 

d1 = {'weight':1, 'data': { 'apples': 8, 'oranges': 7 } }
d2 = {'weight':3, 'data': { 'apples': 4, 'bananas': 3 } }
all_dictionaries = [d1, d2]

mergeDictionariesWithWeight(all_dictionaries)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict

def merge_dictionaries_with_weight(all_dictionaries):
    totals = defaultdict(int)
    result = defaultdict(int)
    for each in all_dictionaries:
        weight = float(each['weight'])
        for key, value in each['data'].items():
            totals[key] += weight
            result[key] += weight * value
    for key, total in totals.items():
       result[key] /= total
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Algorithmically indistinguishable from [gnibbler's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701358/how-do-i-merge-dictionaries-together-using-weights/6701747#6701747), but somehow the generator expression pleases me.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> weights, values = defaultdict(int), defaultdict(int)
>>> key_weight_value = ((key, d['weight'], value) 
                        for d in all_dictionaries 
                        for key, value in d['data'].iteritems())
>>> for k, w, v in key_weight_value:
...     weights[k], values[k] = weights[k] + w, values[k] + w * v
... 

>>> dict((k, values[k] * 1.0 / weights[k]) for k in weights)
{'apples': 5.0, 'oranges': 7.0, 'bananas': 3.0}
```